# MS Excel - If statement (multiple arguments)

Tags: excel, if-statement, ms-office

Having trouble with this one, not sure what I'm missing. Inserting this formula in cell O2. The three cells to the right contain one of three status', "Complete","In Process",or "Incomplete".

If all three cells dispay "Complete" then I want O2 to Display "Complete", if any of the cells display "Complete" but others are "In Process" or "Incomplete" I want it to diplay "In Process", but if all cells are "Incomplete" I want it to display "Incomplete:

Here's my current formula:

```
=If(P2="Complete"AND(Q2="Complete",R2="Complete"),"Complete",IF(P2="Complete"OR(Q2="Complete",R2="Complete")AND(P2="In Process"OR(Q2="In Process",R2="In Process")),"In Process",IF(P2="Incomplete"OR(Q2="Incomplete",R2="Incomplete")AND(P2="In Process"OR(Q2="In Process",R2="In Process")),"In Process", "Incomplete")))
```

Feel like I'm missing an argument or have too many! Thank you greatly for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two If statements and two countif statements to do this.  Count the times Complete is there and if = 3 then add the text Complete, if not 3 then count the Incomplete ones and if = 3 then add the text incomplete, if not 3 then we are In Process

```
=IF(COUNTIF(P2:R2,"Complete")=3,"Complete",IF(COUNTIF(P2:R2,"Incomplete")=3,"Incomplete","In Process"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:   `=IF(AND(P2="complete",Q2="complete",R2="complete"),"Complete",IF(AND(P2="incomplete",Q2="incomplete",R2="incomplete"),"incomplete","In progress"))`

Comment: FYI you don't need the `=TRUE`, as that part of the `If` statement looks to see if that part is `TRUE` by default.